# c++ copies parts of 2d array

Tags: c++

I have written a big program and it has some unexpected behavior so I've made another smaller program to test the issue.

My problem is that for some reason in a 2x2 array whenever I `cin` element `[0][2]`
it also copies to the element `[1][0]`

For example if my array is

```
000
000
000
```

and I input the top right element to 'A' (say) then the middle left element also changes to 'A' and vice versa.
The same issue exists for the elements at `[1][2]` and `[2][0]`

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std ;

char array[2][2];

void display()
{
    cout<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++ )
    {
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++ )
        {
            cout<<array[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++ )
    {
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++ )
        {
            array[i][j]='0';
        }
    }
    display();
    cin>>array[0][2];
    display();
}
```

Comment: You have out of bounds array access. This is Undefined Behaviour and may (or may not) result in what you observed.

Comment: "in a [3][3] array" - Your array is not 3x3, it's 2x2.

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you go out of bounds of the arrays you have. The number when you declare an array is not the top index, it's the number of elements.

Comment: For starters your array is 2x2, meaning  array.0.2 is technically out of bounds, but by magic of allocation is pointing at array.1.0. Array.1.2 is outside allocated space and its behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen how do i repair this?

Comment: Your confusion probably originates from: `array[2]` calls the _third_ element but creating an `array[2]` will give you 2 Elements of size.

Comment: @IcedLance don't arrays start from 0?

Comment: @sanchitverma yes, valid indexes for an `int foo[2]` are `foo[0]` and `foo[1]` but not `foo[2]`.

Comment: When accessing elements, indexes start at 0, but when declaring you write the number of elements(length). So for "int arr[3]" there will be 3 elements with indexes 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access up to `array[2][2]` your array has to be defined as `char array[3][3];`.

Valid indexes for an array `T foo[SIZE]` are `0 ... SIZE - 1`.

Please note that `array` is a very bad name since there is also `std::array<>` and you are using `using namespace std;` which will spill out all symbols from the namespace std into the global namespace.

With

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char array[3][3];

void display()
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << array[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            array[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }

    display();
    cin >> array[0][2];
    display();
}
```

it works as expected:

Output:

```
000
000
000
A

00A
000
000
```